# Asking for the file path with Tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to get a filepath with `askopenfilename()` function but I can't replace the value of my entry (`myEntry`) with the filepath chosen

How can I handle this?

My code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

class Window(Tk):
    def __init__ (self,inTitle="FUNCT"):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title(inTitle)
        self.geometry("500x300")
        self.__myEntry = StringVar(self,"E:/TEST.txt")
        pathfile = Entry(self,textvariable = self.__myEntry, width =80)
        pathfile.grid()
        bouton1 = Button(self, text = "Parcourir", command =self.loadfile)
        bouton1.grid()

    def loadfile(inSelf):
        global filename
        inSelf.filename  = filedialog.askopenfilename()
        return inSelf.filename

myWindow = Window()
myWindow.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of returning the `filename`, you can directly change value of `StringVar` inside of your button's callback.

```
def loadfile(self):
    self.__myEntry.set(filedialog.askopenfilename())
```

Or as suggested by Bryan Oakley in comments, you can remove `StringVar` completely and update `Entry` directly.

```
class Window(Tk):
    def __init__ (self,inTitle="FUNCT"):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title(inTitle)
        self.geometry("500x300")
        self.pathfile = Entry(self, width =80)
        self.pathfile.grid()
        self.pathfile.insert(0, "E:/TEST.txt") #inserts default filename
        bouton1 = Button(self, text = "Parcourir", command =self.loadfile)
        bouton1.grid()

    def loadfile(self):
        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
        self.pathfile.delete(0,END) #removes current text
        self.pathfile.insert(0,filename) #insert the filename
```

Comment: You can also get rid of the `StringVar` and update the entry widget directly.

Comment: @BryanOakley Of course. Edited that alternative as well. Thanks for suggestion. :)